# Gdal version 3s versus 2s: awakward result

Tags: python, gdal

I have a polygon in a kml file.
I wanted to create bounding box of this polygon and save as kml file.
The following code used to work with gdal version 2s. 
But with gdal version 3s, the output kml file shows ocean!
The input kml is certainly belongs to land, far away from ocean.

```
import os, glob, ogr, osr, numpy as np
from shapely.wkt import loads
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

fi = 'AOI.kml'
ds = ogr.Open(fi,0)
slayer = ds.GetLayer(0)

fo = 'AOI_bound.kml'

ods =  ogr.GetDriverByName('kml').CreateDataSource(fo)
srs = osr.SpatialReference()
srs.ImportFromEPSG(4326)

olay = ods.CreateLayer('poly', srs, geom_type=ogr.wkbPolygon) 
olay.CreateField(ogr.FieldDefn('Name', ogr.OFTString))    


for feat in slayer:                    
    poly = loads(str(feat.GetGeometryRef())).envelope

    ogeom = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkb(poly.wkb)
    ofeat = ogr.Feature(olay.GetLayerDefn())    
    ofeat.SetGeometry(ogeom)   
    ofeat.SetField('Name', 'poly')
    olay.CreateFeature(ofeat)
ds = ods = None
```

Comment: Maybe you should try `SetAxisMappingStrategy?( 
OAMS_TRADITIONAL_GIS_ORDER)` https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/rfc73_proj6_wkt2_srsbarn.